# Displaying MySQL results in a single table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created an interface in which the user can choose which results are going to be displayed. The options selected by the user are saved in an array, so the MySQL query goes through the different elements of this array.

So I want to display the results in a single table... something like this:

**Header 1**   | **Header 2**

Result 1-1 | Result 1-2

Result 2-1 | Result 2-2

And my code is the following:

```
$mark = $_POST['mark'];
if (isset($_POST['mark']) && is_array($_POST['mark'])) {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mark); $i++) {
            echo "<th>" . $mark[$i] . "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mark); $i++) {
        $markQuery = "SELECT $mark[$i] FROM marks LIMIT 10";
        $result = mysqli_query($DB_connection, $markQuery);
        echo "<tr>";
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<td>" .  $row[$mark[$i]] . "</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
}
```

I'm not sure about if the second loop is a good idea, but I don't know what should I do to display results as I want.

Comment: I know that this is not the answer to your question but your code is vulnerable to SQL injection as you put unvalidated input to a SQL statement and it is vulnerable to XSS attacks because you output unvalidated user input to HTML which could be used to write any Javascript code into the target webpage.

Comment: You should't query the database every time beacuse it's not efficient way. Instead I would add a new column called `type`, get all records from the table and then filter it by the new column using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting all the columns out first, then add it to the `sql` query, no need to loop the database query.

```
$mark = $_POST['mark'];
if (isset($_POST['mark']) && is_array($_POST['mark'])) {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mark); $i++) {
            echo "<th>" . $mark[$i] . "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    $sql = implode(',', $_POST['marks']);

    $markQuery = "SELECT ".$sql." FROM marks LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($DB_connection, $markQuery);
    echo "<tr>";
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<td>" .  $row[$mark[$i]] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating columns for query in the loop it'll be better to use `implode` function like `$sql = implode(',', $_POST['marks'])`

Comment: @czeski nice observation. I will edit my answer, Thank you

Comment: holpducki and czeski Thanks for your advice.
Finally, I changed my code and using the functions  "implode" and "str_replace" I don't use loops anymore.

eX0du5 I am a totally novice in this field, so I'll try to learn more about what you said. Thanks for the warning!